# Attach Image to Product with Drupal Api

Tags: image, api, drupal, product

I am trying to programatically add products to my drupal commerce store. So far I have been able to add products that contain basic information ( such as sku, title, and price ). How would I be able to add field data, such as images and other field types, using drupal's api.

The code I used to add the products is derived from the commerce_examples/product_example module.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file product_example.module
 * Demonstrates pricing hooks, etc.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 *
 * Simply presents a page that will explain what this module is for.
 * hook_menu() has nothing to do with the checkout page functionality.
 */
function product_example_menu() {
  $items['commerce_examples/product_example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Product Example',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('product_example_info_page'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * This form provides a way to interact with some of the example functions
 * provided here.
 */
function product_example_info_page($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['explanation'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => t('This example demonstrates product creation and manipulation.'),
  );

    $form['product_creation'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Please create a product for use with this example'),
    );
    $types = commerce_product_types();
    $form['product_creation']['product_type'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Product type for product to be created'),
      '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array_keys($types)),
    );
    $form['product_creation']['title'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Product title'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => t('A dummy product for use with product_example'),
    );
    $form['product_creation']['price'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Product price'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#description' => t('A price in decimal format, without a currency symbol'),
      '#default_value' => '100.00',
    );
    $form['product_creation']['product_creation_submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Create product'),
      '#submit' => array('product_example_product_creation_submit')
    );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Submit handler for creating a product.
 */
function product_example_product_creation_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $extras = array(
    'sku' => 'product_example_' . drupal_hash_base64(microtime()),
    'status' => TRUE,
    'uid' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid,
    'title' => $form_state['values']['title'],
  );
  // Use the product example's creation function to create a product.
  $product_id = product_example_create_product($form_state['values']['product_type'], $form_state['values']['price'], $extras);
  drupal_set_message(t('Created sample product with title !title and sku !sku', array('!title' => l($extras['title'], 'admin/commerce/products/' . $product_id), '!sku' => $extras['sku'])));
}

/**
 * Create a product programmatically.
 *
 * This is stolen shamelessly from commerce_bpc. Thanks for the help here!
 *
 * @param $product_type
 *   (string) The name of the product type for which products should be created.
 * @param $price
 *   Decimal amount of price. If additional fields need to be populated they
 *   can be populated in exactly the same way as the commerce_price field.
 * @param $extras
 *   An array for the values of  'extra fields' defined for the product type
 *   entity, or patterns for these. Recognized keys are:
 *   - status
 *   - uid
 *   - sku
 *   - title
 *   Note that the values do NOT come in the form of complex arrays (as they
 *   are not translatable, and can only have single values).
 * @return
 *   The ID of the created product.
 */
function product_example_create_product($product_type, $price, $extras) {
  $form_state = array();
  $form_state['values'] = array();
  $form = array();
  $form['#parents'] = array();

  // Generate a new product object
  $new_product = commerce_product_new($product_type);

  $new_product->status = $extras['status'];
  $new_product->uid = $extras['uid'];

  $new_product->sku = $extras['sku'];
  $new_product->title = $extras['title'];
  $new_product->created = $new_product->changed = time();

  //commerce_price[und][0][amount]
  $price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array(
    'amount' => $price * 100,
    'currency_code' => commerce_default_currency(),
  )));
  $form_state['values']['commerce_price'] = $price;

  // Notify field widgets to save their field data
  field_attach_submit('commerce_product', $new_product, $form, $form_state);

  commerce_product_save($new_product);
  return $new_product->product_id;
}
```

Using the same format the examples uses to add price data:

```
  //commerce_price[und][0][amount]
  $price = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array(
    'amount' => $price * 100,
    'currency_code' => commerce_default_currency(),
  )));
```

I was able to add other field data, however I am still having trouble adding data to the field_productimage field that all commerce products come with by default.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you about other fields data such as extra info related to product. You can add these fields to the product type from the UI or if you are creating product type programmatically then also you can do the same.

Add fields in your form to collect the data e.g -

```
$form['product_creation']['values'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Some data'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#description' => t('Dummy data'),
    );
```

Get those data in your function `product_example_create_product()` by `$form_state()`.

Add them to $new_product object like

```
$new_product->field_name['und'][0]['value'] = $extras['values'];
```

Save the product, just like you are doing.

For the image, you will have to follow the method of file attachment. Like -

```
$file_path = drupal_realpath('image/product_image.png');
  $file = (object) array(
    'uid' => 1,
    'uri' => $file_path,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($file_path),
    'status' => 1,
  );

  // We save the file to the root of the files directory.
  $file = file_copy($file, 'public://');

  $new_product->product_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array)$file;
```

Comment: Using this file attachment method, the image file appears in the files_managed table, so I know drupal is picking it up. However it does not get attached to my products. I believe the problem lies in the last line:
  $new_product->product_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array)$file;
How can I attach the image to the uc_product_image data field once I upload the image to drupal's public directory?